# Probability: Finding the Expected Value of a Random Variable Derived From a Definition.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I recently posted this example, and there's another question  about it I don't really understand.
It says:

> Assume that $Y$ denotes the number of bacteria per cubic
>   centimeter in a particular liquid and that $Y$ has a Poisson
>   distribution with parameter $x$. Further assume that $x$ varies from
>   location to location and has an exponential distribution with
>   parameter $β = 1$. 
>    -Find $E(Y)$

It is known that the PDF for this distribution is: 
$$f(y,x) = e^{-2x}\frac{x^y}{y!}$$

In the lecture slides, it says that $E(Y) = E(E(Y\mid X)) = E(X) = 1$

However, I'm not clear how this is used. I think that we can set up some kind of integral, but I think there could be a faster method than that.

Comment: By "recently posted this example," do you mean http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570383/statistics-deriving-a-joint-probability-function-from-a-definition-of-other-pdf?

Comment: Yes that's it, I was told to make another question by another member.

Comment: I'll bet your lectures slides actually said $E(Y\mid X)$, not $E(X\mid X).$

Comment: Also, why do you have $e^{-2x}$ when the parameter is $x$?

Comment: Made the change. From my lecture slides, in order to get the PDF, the PDF for the Poisson distribution and exponential were multiplied.

Comment: I guess that is actually the joint PDF, not the conditional one. By other hand, have you tried to compute $E[Y \mid X]$? Do you know what is the expected value for a Poisson distribution? That would be a good start ;)

Comment: In order to find $E(Y \mid X)$ I have to integrate $y f(Y \mid X)$ right?
I'm still a bit confused, the integral isn't coming along nicely, and I have a feeling that a trick can be used to get the answer relatively quickly, but I just don't see it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, hopefully those hints would be enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are facing well-known distributions like the Poisson, usually you don't have to derive its mean, you just have to use what is known about it, unless you are required to do so, but I think that is not the case here.

**Hint #1:** $f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $x$. So, $E[Y \mid X=x]$ is just the [mean of a Poisson random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Mean) with parameter $x$.

**"Hint" #2**: After Hint #1 you should find that $E[Y \mid X=x]=x$. Note that this expected value (*a number!*) has the same form for any value of $x$, therefore we can write $E[Y \mid X] = X$. Since $X$ is a random variable, $E[Y \mid X]$ is also a *random variable* that happens to be equal to $X$, and therefore $E[E[Y \mid X]] = E[X]$. Be aware that $E[Y \mid X]$ is a function of $X$, not $Y$, and in that way the outer expected value operator is taken respect to $X$.

**Hint #3**: Take at look at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7a4bjE6Crk&feature=youtu.be&t=7m45s) to find out *what else* $E[E[Y \mid X]]$ is according to the iterated expectations law.